# Python generator to yield everything from another generator call

Tags: python, recursion, generator, yield

I have a Python generator that can call itself to get more elements to yield.  It looks like this:

```
def gen(list):
    # ...
    if list:
        for x in gen(list[1:]):
            yield x
```

My question is about the last two lines: is there a more concise way to express this?  I am hoping for something like this (understanding this isn't valid Python as-is):

```
def gen(list):
    # ...
    if list:
        yield each in gen(list[1:])
```

Comment: I don't quite get what this is supposed to do, I originally thought it was just a naive way of converting a list to a generator but I was mistaken.  Could you enlighten me?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that code looks like it would always return an empty list. I assume there must be other yields in the comment?

Comment: @Dunes: yes, there are other yields in the comment.

Comment: @Davy8: it's not a wrapper or converter, it's a custom generator I wrote.  It takes a list of things and generates another list, which may contain some of the same things, or not.  A "filter" of sorts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Python 3.3 [added the `yield from` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380).  Here's a comparison between what you currently have and code using the new keyword:

`yield_from_test.py`:

```
def gen_for(a_list):
    if a_list:
        yield a_list[0]
        for x in gen_for(a_list[1:]):
            yield x

def gen_yield(a_list):
    if a_list:
        yield a_list[0]
        yield from gen_yield(a_list[1:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert list(gen_for([1,2,3])) == list(gen_yield([1,2,3]))
    print(list(gen_yield([1,2,3])))
```

`» python3 yield_from_test.py 
[1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 26):

There's been some call for a `yield from` or the like that "passes through" all the values returned by a subgenerator. See [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) for some ideas that have been bounced around. However, nothing has been implemented yet. Your first example is correct.

Comment: Note: Python 3.3 has been released, along with PEP 380 (yield from).

Answer (score 6):

Your code sample is very idiomatic and concise, no need and no real chance for further improvements and especially not when it comes at readability.

Comment: Node generators have [a syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) for delegating generation to another generator: `yield* my_generator(...)`.  I personally find that more concise.  And things become idiomatic with a PEP and adoption...

Answer (score 4):

Your first example is the proper solution.